# Prevent iframe zoom on Android

Tags: android, html, mobile

I have an iframe that contains some form elements.  I have tried putting the meta tag within the iframe page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

as well as setting the css for the input:

```
input[type="text"] {font-size: 1em;}
```

Neither seem to work if the form is within an iframe.  If the user taps the text input, it still zooms in.  Is it possible to prevent zoom in this case?  I am using Android 4.2.1 on an S3.

edit:  I have found the CSS does work, I just wasnt setting large enough.  Unfortunately this also breaks the layout.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
touch-action: none
```

I am unsure if android supports this yet.  It was originally only for IE as ms-touch-action.
Here's some more info: http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/touch-action